# integral involving error function (erf)

Tags: integration, logarithms, approximation, closed-form, error-function

Does anybody know if a closed form of this integral exist?

$\int \mbox{erf}(x) \ln(\mbox{erf}(x)) \Bbb dx$

where erf is so called error function.

In case there is no closed form solution. Is it possible to get an approximate one?

Comment: Closed-form: A closed form for a primitive of that beast seems unlikely. Approximate expression: are you sure you need an approximate expression for an *indefinite* integral?

Comment: A 1969 paper by JPL scientists provides a [table of integrals of the error functions](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf), might that be helpful? There is also an addendum [here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/75B/jresv75Bn3-4p149_A1b.pdf)

Comment: Integrating by parts and simplifying, we have $$-I=-\int_0^\infty\text{erf}(x)~\ln\text{erf}(x)~dx ~=~ \lambda+\frac1{\sqrt\pi}~,$$ where $$\lambda~=~\lim_{t\to0}~\frac{\ln\text{erf}(t)}{\sqrt\pi} ~+~ \frac2\pi\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-2x^2}}{\text{erf}(x)}~dx,$$ whose numerical value is about $$\lambda\simeq-0.2427834044630287264768290\dots$$

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Thanks for the reply. I think the main culprit here is the 'Log of that beast (erf)' :(

However, in my purpose an approximation is sufficient. In fact I want to compare the solution of a numerical model with the analytical expression that contains the above integral. Just comparison purpose, an approximation applying any special condition may be enough. By the way, for practical applications, range of x can also be considered as [0, infinite] or even [0, to any finite number] if that helps with anything.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the link! Interesting stuff! But somehow, anything involving log(erf) seems to be missing :(

Comment: @Lucian Thanks a million for your input and effort. But what I am looking for is an expression that is a function of the variable x. So, can we simplify the second term of lamda as a non-integral form?

Comment: @MuhammadMuniruzzaman: If by absurd such a function were to exist $($I am quite positive that it doesn't$),$ one way of guessing just what exactly it might be, is by trying to find a closed form expression for the definite integral I already presented. Speaking of which, we have $$\lambda~=~\dfrac{\ln2-\ln\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt\pi}~+~\lambda_0,$$ where $$\lambda_0~=~\lim_{t\to0}~\frac{\ln t}{\sqrt\pi} ~+~ \frac2\pi\int_t^\infty\frac{e^{-2x^2}}{\text{erf}(x)}~dx,$$ whose numerical value is about $$\lambda_0\simeq-0.3109274848144238645910\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\erf{\operatorname{erf}}$
Substitute [inverse erf](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html) $\erf(x)=t$ and apply tabular integration:

$$\int\erf(x)\ln(\erf(x))dx=\int t\ln(t) d\text{erf}^{-1}(t)=x\erf(x)\ln(\erf(x))+\frac1{\sqrt\pi}(\ln(\erf(x))+1) e^{-x^2}+\int\frac{\int_0^t\erf^{-1}(w)dw}tdt$$

Now apply $\erf^{-1}(x)$’s [series expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/06/01/02/0004/):

$$\int\frac{\int_0^t\erf^{-1}(w)dw}tdt=C-\frac{\ln(t)}{\sqrt\pi}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_nt^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)^2(2n+1)}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right)^{2n+1}$$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{\int\erf(x)\ln(\erf(x))dx=C+x\erf(x)\ln(\erf(x))+ e^{-x^2}\frac{\ln(\erf(x))}{\sqrt\pi}-\frac{\ln(\erf(x))}{\sqrt\pi}+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt\pi}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n\erf^{2n+2}(x)}{(2n+2)^2(2n+1)}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right)^{2n+1};a_0=1,a_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_ma_{n-m-1}}{(m+1)(2m+1)}}$$

The Mathematica code (`%p`)

`E^(-x^2)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]+Log[Erf[x]](E^(-x^2)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]+x Erf[x])+ReplaceAll[t->Erf[x]][Integrate[1/t Integrate[Normal[Series[InverseErf[w],{w,0,c}]],{w,0,t}]-1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]]t),t]]`

for large $c$ and

`{NIntegrate[Erf[x] Log[Erf[x]],{x,a,b}],ReplaceAll[x->b][%p]-ReplaceAll[x->a][%p]}`

for given $a,b,p$ verifies this result